# Cox regression - categorizing variables

Tags: r, cox-model

I am trying to use a Cox regression model (in R) to examine the effect of postpartum disease on fertility in cattle - I have been advised to use calving-to-conception interval (in days) as my parameter for fertility.

I have the following data available:

Date of calving|
Date of conception|
Calving to conception interval (days)|
Postpartum disease (1= yes, 0=no)|
Conception (pregnant=1, not pregnant=0)|
Date of pregnancy diagnosis|
Date when cow left the study|
Days at risk of abortion|
Abortion (1= no abortion, 0=aborted)|

Should I re-categorise the calving-to-conception interval as a binary variable (say from the median number of days)? This would then give me a 'short' and a 'large' calving interval. This is because I am investigating the effect of postpartum disease on the calving interval (parameter indicating fertility i.e. the rate of calving to conception).

Comment: As this subject area is completely foreign to me, can you simplify it? What is the survival parameter (conception?), the time parameter (I do not understand days at risk/calving etc...). Is the disease present at the entering stage, or can a subject get it in the middle of the time in the data?